# Не активные ссылки

Tags: html, css

Учусь делать сайты,уже 3ий сайт верстаю.При верстке это сайта заметил что ссылки не активны.
Что могло произойти?

[Посмотреть сайт](https://frallen.github.io/New/)

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 1500px;
  /*ПИСАТЬ ЛУЧШЕ МИНВИДТХ */
  height: 7770px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lato regular', sans-serif;
  color: #8c8f94;
}

header {
  background: url("..//img/headerbg.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  height: 1000px;
}

.main-navigation {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.Right-menu {
  float: right;
}

.Left-menu {
  float: left;
}

.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: #26272d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation a:hover {
  color: #b5b5b6;
}

#GetApp {
  margin-top: -15px;
  background: #267df4;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 24px 14px 48px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.fa-apple::before {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-bars {
  position: relative;
  right: 380px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

.Logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3e3f45;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.Whats {
  text-align: center;
}

.Whats h1 {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Whats p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 780px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

.Whats a {
  padding: 18px 47px 18px 67px;
  border: 1px solid #dddfe1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #26272d;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.fa-play::before {
  position: relative;
  right: 160px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <nav class="main-navigation">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul class="Left-menu">
        <li><a href="">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="Right-menu">
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="GetApp" class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true">Get App</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h1 class="Logo"><span class="bold">New</span>Providence</h1>
    </nav>
    <div class="Whats">
      <h1>What happens tomorrow?</h1>
      <p>The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.</p>
      <a href="">Watch Video</a>
      <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Что значит не активны?

Comment: У тебя атрибут `href` пустой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Атрибут `href` для тега `<a></a>` является обязательным, в Вашем же случае он попросту пустой.

Пример реализации ссылки:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Если же вы пока не хотите указывать ссылку, то можете сделать следующим образом:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Something</a>
```